# ¿Como implementar una capa de proyección a la salida de una Red Neuronal Recurrente?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, redes-neuronales, lstm

Hola y gracias de antemano.

Estoy tratando de implementar una red LSTM que encontré en el artículo [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10468v6). En el **Párrafo 3** de la **Secc. 4.1** se muestra el modelo que deseo implementar y dice:

> *The d-vector model is a 3-layer LSTM network with a final linear layer.*
> *Each LSTM layer has 768 nodes, with projection of 256 nodes.*

He hecho éste código:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype("float32")/255.0
x_test = x_test.astype("float32")/255.0

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add( layers.Input(shape=(None,28)) )
model.add( layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True) )
model.add( layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True) )
model.add( layers.LSTM(50, activation='linear') )

print(model.summary())

model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, verbose=2)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

Quisiera agregar la *proyección de 256 nodos* al modelo creado en el código anterior. Cabe resaltar que en el artículo hay una cita a otro artículo[[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1128) como se muestra a continuación.

> *The d-vector model is a 3-layer LSTM network with a final linear layer.*
> *Each LSTM layer has 768 nodes, **with projection[[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1128) of 256 nodes**.*

En la **Fig. 1** de la **Sección 2** en [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1128) muestran la arquitectura de la red que es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la **Eq. 13** definen la proyección como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho esto mis dudas realmente son:
¿En keras o tensorflow habrá implementada alguna capa que se le pueda agregar a un modelo LSTM para implementar la arquitectura de la **Fig. 1**?, ¿Habrá en keras o tensorflow algún modelo ya implementado con la arquitectura de la **Fig. 1**? o ¿Estará implementado ese modelo en algún lugar?

Disculpen la extensión de la pregunta, es que quisiera asegurarme que el modelo no está implementado antes de batallar con eso dado que no se nada de tensorflow y para ello tendría que aprender a usarlo. Ya he experimentado el dolor de tener que implementar algo y luego encontrarlo hecho.

Si hay algún error en el código ya escrito, por favor, me corrigen. Saludos y nuevamente gracias!!!

Comment: Tensorflow y keras te ayudan a crear tus modelos, no creo que estén hechos para crear desde 0 una red neuronal. Estos modelos te proveen de herramientas y depende de ti como las utilizas y cuáles utilizas

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes

### 1. Significado del texto

> The d-vector model is a 3-layer LSTM network with a final linear layer. Each LSTM layer has 768 nodes, with projection of 256 nodes.

Sin saber el contexto de donde está escrito, **una proyección** se da cuando tienes una multiplicación matricial (es lo que ocurre constantemente en las redes neuronales). Y tras el resultado de dicha multiplicación te queda un **espacio dimensional enorme**, pongamos 50.000 mil dimensiones. Los ordenadores actuales no tienen capacidad para tratar con esa cantidad de datos, por lo que tienes que hacer una **proyección** a un espacion dimensional inferior, por ejemplo 500 dimensiones. Es decir, una **reducción de dimensionalidad**

Las **reducciones de dimensionalidad** consisten basicamente en algoritmos que pueden ser de dos tipos:

1. Unos identifican las partes más importantes que hay en un conjunto de datos y se quedan con ellas desechando las menos importantes.
2. Otros que crean nuevos datos en un espacio dimensional inferior, pero que representa, al conjunto de datos de espacio dimensional superior con alta fidelidad.

En el mundo de la redes neuronales y la inteligencia artificial es muy usado en el tratamiento del lenguaje, tanto en lenguaje escrito como en lenguaje hablado.

### 2. Aplicación a tu problema

Llevando esto a tu problema (repito sin saber el contexto de esa frase que pones). En ese artículo la persona ha creado las tres capas LSTM reduciendo su salida. Para hacer esto en Tensorflow puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Crear manualmente la capa LSTM.
2. Realizar algún tipo de imitación de las siguientes maneras
   con un cortado (`Cropping`), o alguna operación de covolución (`Conv`), o cualquier otra reducción de tamaño mediante otra operación implementada por ti manualmente.

### Bonus

- No sé los conocimientos que tienes, pero intuyo por el código que cualquiera de las soluciones está algo alejada de tus conocimientos, mi recomendación es que sigas **tutoriales básicos que te enseñen bien que está haciendo cada operación**.
- Aclarar que el modulo `Keras` de tensorflow esta pensado para desarrollar redes neuronales de una forma rápida y sin complicaciones, esto tiene la desventaja de que te quita **poder de manipulación** de las operaciones matemáticas que suceden. Por ello la solución a tu problema no es tan simple como poner:

```
#El parametro output_shape no existe
layers.LSTM(768, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, output_shape=(256,))
```

Comment: **Muchas gracias** por la respuesta, no me sirven esos enfoques pero me ilustraron el camino que debo tomar, _creo que tendré que implementar el modelo_ con tensorflow, aunque primero tengo que aprender a usarlo bien. Editaré la pregunta para dar un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Hola Omar! Tu edición ya está respondida en mi respuesta, te lo resumo para que quede claro. Lo que tu pretendes hacer no existe en Tensorflow, no hay ninguna función que lo reproduzca y lo tienes que hacer manualmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!